# Binomial inequalities and characteristics of integers

Tags: inequality, quadratics, integers

I had the following question on a test, and I'm really confused about how to obtain the answer. The correct answer is F) Less than 1, but I just can't grasp my head around why.

```
Given a > b, and (a - b) > (a^2 - b^2), then (a + b) must be: 
F) Less than 1
G) Greater than 1
H) Greater than a
J) Greater than (a - b)
K) Equal to (a - b)
```

I think the method to solve this question involves expanding the binomial (a^2 - b^2), which results in (a + b) * (a - b), but if you take (a - b) to the left side of the original inequality, wouldn't the result just be 0 > (a + b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go with your idea about factoring the difference of squares, and thus see that:

$$a-b > a^2 - b^2 \implies a-b > (a-b)(a+b)$$

Since $a>b$ is given, then $a-b \ne 0$ (and in particular, $a-b > 0$) and we can divide both sides of the right-hand inequality by $a-b$. Doing so, we see a cancellation and obtain the following:

$$a-b > (a-b)(a+b) \implies \frac{a-b}{a-b} > \frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{a-b} \implies 1 > a+b$$

I think the main issue is just a slight lapse in thought since you seem to have been thinking along the lines of subtracting $a-b$ (thus the $0$ in your post) instead of dividing (which would give you the $1$).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was able to figure it right before you posted your answer, but I'll give it to you for the effort! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out my problem. My brain somehow thought of subtracting (a - b) instead of dividing (a - b). After dividing, the resulting inequality is 1 > (a + b)

Careless mistake!

Edit: Since (a - b) is not negative here, the inequality sign should be kept the same. However, if (a - b) was negative, it would be necessary to reverse the inequality sign.

Comment: But you can't just divide both sides of an inequality by something. If the something is negative, the direction of the inequality switches. (And if the something is zero, all Hell breaks loose).

Comment: Thanks, I realize that. (a - b) here in this case is not negative, so I'm pretty sure it's fine.

Comment: Yes, in this case it's fine – but if you want people to know that you know what you're talking about, you have to put in those details explicitly.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll edit my answer accordingly.